# Sessions in php not working as expected

Tags: php, session

I have a file "test.php" like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['ph']);
require 'connection.php';
if(!session_id())
    session_start();
else
{
    echo session_id();
    echo "<br>";
    echo var_dump($_SESSION);
}
$ph = 0;
if(isset($_POST['ph']))
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $ph = $_POST['ph'];
        $q1 = "select PHONE_CUST_ID from PHONE where PHONE_NO = :ph_bv";
        $prepare = oci_parse($conn, $q1);
        oci_bind_by_name($prepare, ':ph_bv', $ph);
        oci_execute($prepare);
        $res = oci_fetch_array($prepare, OCI_ASSOC);
        if(!$res)
            header('Location:newcustomer.php');
        else
            header('Location:oldcustomer.php');
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>  
    <form method="POST" action="" id="custphoneform">
        <label for="PhoneNumber">Enter Phone Number:</label>
        <input type="number" name="ph" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The "oldcustomer.php" and "newcustomer.php" have similar code as below:

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['ph']))
{
    echo $_SESSION['ph'];
}
else
    echo "Not found";
?>
```

The session variable is not working, gives me the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: ph in D:\xampp\htdocs\myfiles\newcustomer.php on line 4
```

The session works properly if I set the "form action" to some value but I don't want that. I want redirection based on user input. How to achieve it?

Example:

```
"test.php"
 Enter Phone Number: 100
```

Based on the above value i.e. 100 I want to direct the user to different pages. If the number exists in the DB then `oldcustomer.php` otherwise `newcustomer.php`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Your session was not set.

Comment: The session is set. I checked but omitted the code here to make it shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't give any value for  `action` attribute here, So it will always post the data on current page only which is `test.php`. So you are getting error at `oldcustomer.php` when you are trying to access the variable.

```
 <form method="POST" action="" id="custphoneform">
```

either you can directly post your data to `oldcustomer.php` by specifying it in action attribute as

```
 <form method="POST" action="oldcustomer.php" id="custphoneform">
```

or you should store your data in `$_SESSION` global variable so you can access it anywhere in your project as

```
 $_SESSION['ph'] = $_POST['ph'];
```

use this variable in `oldcustomer.php` as

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['ph'])){
        echo $_SESSION['ph'];
    }else{
        echo "Phone number not found";
    }
?>
```

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to post it to a page which is predefined. If I do that then it will always go to the `oldcustomer.php`, but I want to redirect based on the input.

Comment: then you should post your form using ajax to the specified url

Comment: you are getting error in `newcustomer.php` and `oldcustomer.ph` just because you are trying to access the data from `$_POST['ph']`. data is not posted on that page, so remove these lines

Comment: I have changed the code, that's why I am asking you to read the comments.

Comment: where you changed, it is still same <?php
session_start();
if(!empty($_POST['ph']))
    $_SESSION['ph'] = $_POST['ph']; 
echo $_SESSION['ph'];
?>

Comment: you should change this file contents

Comment: `<?php require 'connection.php'; session_start(); echo $_SESSION['ph']; ?>` – Karan Gupta 10 mins ago

Comment: change your `oldcustomer.php` and `newcustomer.php` file man, errors are on that page, not on `test.php` page

Comment: I did exactly what you said. The session works, but only once. The next time I enter a value in the form, it shows me the previous value only. Here's the code for `xxxcustomer.php` <?php
require 'connection.php';
`session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['ph']))
{
 echo $_SESSION['ph'];
}
else
 echo "Not found";
?>`

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the session value does not change. It remains the same no matter what I input.

Comment: use `if(isset(($_SESSION['ph']))unset($_SESSION['ph']);` in `test.php` just after the `session_start();`

Comment: The var_dump doesn't give me anything now. I am updating my code in the question. Please check

Comment: The output to the new code is: `lrjd153ggjba6p1t3ct56lc5c6
array(0) { }`

Comment: Ok i got it. I missed the lines `$_SESSION['ph'] = $_POST['ph'];` in `test.php`. Thank you very much bro.

Comment: check the my comment, and you should add these line only your previous code, why you changed your whole code

Comment: and please don't change the questions here, according to answer, otherwise the answers given by others become useless and didn't help the further users. change your project code according to answer and give proper reply what error you are getting after that

Comment: Noted. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You are redirecting after form post. At that time new request will be initialize which doesn't contain post data. Whsat you can do is in `test.php` assign session which will then use in any page

**test.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'connection.php';

$ph = 0;
if(isset($_POST['ph']))
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $ph = $_POST['ph'];
        $q1 = "select PHONE_CUST_ID from PHONE where PHONE_NO = :ph_bv";
        $prepare = oci_parse($conn, $q1);
        oci_bind_by_name($prepare, ':ph_bv', $ph);
        oci_execute($prepare);
        $res = oci_fetch_array($prepare, OCI_ASSOC);
        if(!empty($_POST['ph']))
        $_SESSION['ph'] = $_POST['ph']; //assign value to session
        if(!$res)
            header('Location:newcustomer.php');
        else
            header('Location:oldcustomer.php');
    }
?>
```

**oldcustomer.php** and **newcustomer.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['ph'];
?>
```

Comment: I am already checking with the `$_POST['ph']` in the beginning. Only if the data is posted it will check in the database, but anyway its not working. I get the same error.

Comment: Have you trysame code as i suggest? I forgot `session_start();` in begining. Add it then try

Comment: Yeah, I just added the lines in my code. I had tried this earlier also but it didn't work.

Comment: Remove `if(!empty($_POST['ph']))
    $_SESSION['ph'] = $_POST['ph']; ` from `oldcustomer.php` and `newcustomer.php`

Comment: Same Same Same. :(

Comment: Move `session_start();` at the top of page in `test.php`

Comment: After banging my head for 2 hours and trying all these things I have posted this question lol.

Comment: If you still getting same error then your session value not set. Try to check session values

Comment: I did `echo session_id();` just after `session_start` and here's the value:
`lrjd153ggjba6p1t3ct56lc5c6`

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION);` and see the output

Comment: `array(1) { ["ph"]=> string(5) "55555" } lrjd153ggjba6p1t3ct56lc5c6`

Comment: It means your session has value of `ph` so `<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['ph'];
?>` code must working for oldcustomer.php and newcustomer.php

Comment: I know it should, if I set the form action then it works perfectly. I will have to add another page if this doesn't work. Can it be done using javascript or any other language?

Comment: No without action its should work also. Because session cna work on any page. Only you have to remove `$_POST` from `oldcustomer.php and newcustomer.php ` pages

Comment: Could you try if it works? You won't have the oldcustomer working but the `newcustomer.php` should work.

Comment: Yes I have tried and its working.(for newcustomer.php). Show your `newcustomer.php` code

Comment: Well, then I have no clue why its not working. I have recently formatted my pc too, so there shouldn't be any problems. Thanks for the help anyway, if you do get the solution then please comment here.

Comment: `<?php
require 'connection.php';
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['ph'];
?>`

Answer (score 0):

you redirect to xxxcustomer.php (by the line `header('Location: ...);`. That will be a GET request.

So $_POST is empty.

So the if() will not be executed. { } are missing so the echo line will be executed next.

But no $_SESSION['ph'] is set >>> warning missing index ph

**edit**
I suppose you better do an include() on those xxxcustomer.php files?

**EDIT 2**

As you changed your code in the question, this answer makes no sense anymore.
Bottom line remains: after a redirect you loose the values in $_POST as it no longer is a POST-request

Comment: include will pickup the contents of the file specified a place that code (excluding the opening <?php) in that place. So the session_start() in the included file will have to go. After executing the included code, php will continue to the next line in the main script. If that is not intended, make sure to stop executing using exit() or a if-statement around your include

Comment: so i should include `test.php` in `xxxcustomer.php` or the other way round?

Comment: the other way around: